# Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Software caused connection abort: recv failed"

Tags: android, debugging

I just want to debug my app. First I click the debug button, then click attach debugger to Android process and select my app process, then I get the following message:

> Error running Android Debugger (8614):
>   Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Software caused connection abort: recv failed"

Notice: I'm using Genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I get that message when i'm trying to attach the debugger when the debugger is already attached. When you click on the debug button it runs your app and attach the debbuger to the device.